# How is gcc -llibrary flag interpreted?

Tags: gcc

How is `gcc -llibrary` flag interpreted?

How can `gcc -llept` be linked if library filename is `liblept.*` not `lept.*`?

Comment: Did you even bother to look at the docs?

Comment: @CarlNorum: Well, it did take me awhile to find it.

Comment: `man gcc` followed by a search for `-llibrary` turns it up immediately for me.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Ah, sorry.  I don't have it installed, had to rely on ze internetz.

Answer (score 1):

From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options

> The only difference between using an -l option and specifying a file
>   name is that -l surrounds library with ‘lib’ and ‘.a’ and searches
>   several directories.